# Phrase for "forced to do a lot of mental work"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Today I read a beautiful metaphor for *being forced to perform more brain activity than needed if there would have been a proper and clear explanation*:

> The essay lacked a proper structure: "The reader **had to perform mental gymnastics** to understand it."

I think it's a beautiful phrase but I would like to have a larger arsenal of similar phrases with a similar meaning.

Do you know any?

Comment: Hi @Kris, I ment phrases with a similar meaning to 'performing mental gymnastics'.

Comment: ... Your 'comment', if correct, means that your question needs correcting: 'being put through the wringer' and 'think very hard' are not synonymous.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth. I found a nice solution in that question itself:
*"The unstructured essay made the reader feel like he was solving a very confusing riddle."*

Or a bit more provocative: 
*"... made the reader feel like a detective solving a murder crime."*

Reading applications for *being put through the wringer* gives me the impression that one is most accurate in situations where the writer creates difficulty for the reader consciously.
For this example, I would like it to illustrate that created confusion might be an effect of laziness but is not intentional.

Comment: There's a quaint old expression, usually in the first person: "I'll have to put on my thinking hat."

Answer (score 0):

A popular option is "*rack (or wrack) one's brains (or brain)*". Like "I've been racking my brains trying to come up with the answer."

There is also a less used UK option - "chew the cud", which means a process of really poring over something and contemplating it deeply. Perhaps not exactly forced to think but close to it.

Comment: I'm very happy with your *"rack one's brain"* solution @NoTearsInMyTea. This time, I will choose the 'detective version' from the comment above, because of the provocativeness. But I will definitely try rack one's brain as well soon.